# Quote: "No more effective device has yet been invented to prevent one man from helping another as writing a book"

Tags: quote-source

I thought I once heard something like the following quote:

> No more effective device has yet been invented to prevent one man from helping another as writing a book.

or maybe

> There is no more effective device to excuse a man from helping others as writing a book.

I also thought I heard that it was by C. S. Lewis.

I can't find it anywhere.  Does it ring a bell for anyone?